# How to add text-area and select to the Alert in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, alert

I am working on Ionic App and I want to show I am showing the input fields in the alert but the problem is that, I am not able to show the textarea and the select box in the alert controller.

This is my **popupdetails.ts** file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, LoadingController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-checkout',
  templateUrl: 'checkout.html',
})
export class CheckoutPage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
    public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private alertCtrl: AlertController) {
  }

  presentPrompt() {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Submit Shipping Details',
      inputs: [
        {
          name: 'name',
          placeholder: 'Name'
        },
        {
          name: 'mobilenumber',
          placeholder: 'Mobile Number',
          type: 'number'
        },
        {
          name: 'pincode',
          placeholder: 'Pincode',
          type: 'number'
        },
        {
          name: 'state',
          placeholder: 'State',
        },
        {
          name: 'city',
          placeholder: 'City',
        },
        {
          name: 'address',
          placeholder: 'Address',
        },
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: data => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Submit',
          handler: data => {
            console.log('Submit clicked');
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    alert.present();
  }
}
```

In this, I have used the alert controller to the input fields but the problem is that, I am not able to show the textarea and the select box in the alert controller.

**This is my output currently coming.**

[image]

**I want this type of output with textarea and the select box.**

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: @ManojBhardwaj. Okay, So for the modal, I have to create a different page in Ionic?

Comment: yes you can also customize the page according to yourself i mean use one modal with ngIf and use same page into different as reuseable thank you

Comment: @ManojBhardwaj. Can you please code and paste as a answer?

Comment: @ManojBhardwaj. Okay.

Comment: Please check may hope it will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-x1os3c please check this link may hope it will help you[image]

```
<ion-content padding style="background:white">
 <ion-list no-lines>
<form>
<p style="font-weight:bold">Name</p>
<ion-item>
<ion-label hidden></ion-label>
<ion-input style="border:1px solid black" type='text'></ion-input>
 </ion-item>

<p style="font-weight:bold">Mobile</p>
  <ion-item>
<ion-label hidden></ion-label>
<ion-input style="border:1px solid black" type='tel'></ion-input>
 </ion-item>
  <p style="font-weight:bold">Country</p>
 <ion-item>
 <ion-label hidden></ion-label>
 <ion-input style="border:1px solid black" readonly="true" type='text'></ion-input>
</ion-item>
</form>
 <ion-grid>
 <ion-row>
 <ion-col>
  <button color="secondary" ion-button float-right>Add</button>
  <button color="light" ion-button float-right>Close</button>
  </ion-col>
 </ion-row>
</ion-grid>

 </ion-list>  
</ion-content>
```